# How to install the apk in Google Glass

Tags: installation, apk, google-glass, sample

How to install the Sample apk in Google Glass?
I am new to Google Glass. I didn't have glass. I developed a sample "Hello world" application in Google Glass. I did not know how to istall the apk without Glass. I tried in Samsung s4 and Google Nexus 4. Then What are the steps to install the Glass app with and without Google Glass.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, you can't

without google glasses you cant test your application over the Android Mobile or emulator.

Next, installation of google glass application is same as installing .apk in mobile device.

Comment: Some Websites i referred. In that they posted "We can run the Google Glass Application without Glass". For that we have to install some Apk files. https://github.com/zhuowei/Xenologer.

Comment: I tried solution from that blog, but not succeed, yes but you can create a handout from that way to show glass running apps to mobile.

Comment: Is it possible to install the Google Glass app in the mobile after installing that Glass Framework.

Comment: No,it is not possible to install the Google Glass app in the mobile after installing that Glass Framework. –

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your valuable comments.

Comment: Hi. I have another doubt. What are the ways to launch the Glass application. Eg: Through voice command. Through only voice command we launch glass application? How to register the voice command.

Comment: Can you please send me the Sample Glass application that works perfectly in Google Glass.